# Highcharts - Highstock chart showing double line on hovering data points to show tooltip

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization, react-highcharts

Highstock chart showing double line on hovering data points to show the tooltip, which supose to be single and should be in sync.

AS one can check in foddle (link shared below and in snashot) the line on hovering are double and somewhat not in sync. In series second object(2end series), if we set xaxis as 0 or remove it then this issue disappears but xaxis labels also gets removed. I need both the xaxis labels and single line on hover.

I am sharing the link to the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/akt6284m/2/

code:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [
      {
         "type":"areaspline",
         "color":"rgba(87,169,222,0.8)",
     
         "data":[
          {
               "y":0,
               "x":1608737040000,
               
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "x":1608737100000,
            
            },
            {
               "y":2,
               "x":1608737160000,
               
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "x":1608737220000,
              
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "x":1608737280000,
              
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "x":1608737340000,
              
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "x":1608737400000,
              
            },
           ....
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"column",
           "groupPadding":0,
        
         "showInLegend":false,
                 "yAxis":1,
                "xAxis":1,
         "data":[
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737040000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
              
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737100000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
          
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737160000,
               "color":"#FF3635",
               
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737220000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
             
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737280000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
             
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737340000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
              
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737400000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
             
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "x":1608737460000,
               "color":"#02DE27",
             
            },
           ....
         ],
         "label":{
            "format":""
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"scatter",
       
         "data":[
            [
               1608737160000,
               0
            ],
            [
               1608738060000,
               0
            ]
         ],
         "color":"#FF3635"
      } 
   ],
    yAxis: [{
        height: '50%'
    }, {
        height: '50%',
        top: '50%'
    }],
    xAxis: [{
         tickLength: 0,
        lineWidth: 1, 
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
       
        height: '50%'
    }, {
     
        top: '50%',
        height: '50%',
    }]
});
```

[image]

Please if anyone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The column series has different padding for the `xAxis` by default. Try to use this config for the xAxis which is assigned to the line series.

```
  xAxis: [{
    minPadding: 0.021,
    maxPadding: 0.021,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    height: '50%'
  }, {

    top: '50%',
    height: '50%',

  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eu94vcta/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxPadding

Comment: But  then minPadding & maxPadding need to be set again is count of columns/bars changes.

Comment: @user2865480 just to be sure - using one xAxis is not a solution for you? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rm9stypg/